# Searching in database with any filter

Tags: java, sql, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I've create a GUI with a jTable to show data to the user, and the user can search with any filter he wants, but, I need to identify with a jTextField is empty or filled.
So, how to check if a jTextField isn't empty and make the else if works?

Example, the user insert a name (jTextFieldNOME) and click on the jButton without writing in another jTextField (there's another 3 or 4 jTextField's following a similar pattern).

what's happening now is only running the first else if:`else if(jTextFieldNOME.getText() != null)`

```
if(jTextFieldNOME.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldCPF.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldIDADEMIN.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldIDADEMAX.getText().equals("")){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vazios\n");
            PreparedStatement stm=cn.prepareStatement("select * from cad_pessoa ");
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            
            DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel) jTableDADOS.getModel();
            tm.setRowCount(0);
        
        while(rs.next()){
            
            Object o []= {rs.getString("cad_cpf"), rs.getString("cad_nome"), rs.getString("cad_apelido"), rs.getString("cad_idade"), rs.getDate("cad_data")};
            tm.addRow(o);
                
        }
            
        }

        else if(jTextFieldNOME.getText() != null) {
        
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select cad_nome,cad_apelido,cad_cpf,cad_idade,cad_data from cad_pessoa where cad_nome like ? order by cad_nome asc, cad_cpf asc nulls last ");
        ps.setString(1,"%" + jTextFieldNOME.getText() + "%");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ps.execute();
            
        
        DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel) jTableDADOS.getModel();
        tm.setRowCount(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "nomes\n");
        while(rs.next()){
            
            Object o []= {rs.getString("cad_cpf"), rs.getString("cad_nome"), rs.getString("cad_apelido"), rs.getString("cad_idade"), rs.getDate("cad_data")};
            tm.addRow(o);
            
            
        }
        }
        
        else if (jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText() != null){
            
            PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select cad_nome,cad_apelido,cad_cpf,cad_idade,cad_data from cad_pessoa where cad_apelido like ? order by cad_nome asc, cad_cpf asc nulls last ");
        ps.setString(1,"%" + jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText() + "%");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ps.execute();
            
        
        DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel) jTableDADOS.getModel();
        tm.setRowCount(0);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "apelidos\n");
        while(rs.next()){
            
            Object o []= {rs.getString("cad_cpf"), rs.getString("cad_nome"), rs.getString("cad_apelido"), rs.getString("cad_idade"), rs.getDate("cad_data")};
            tm.addRow(o);

        }
        
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after some research here and some tutorials, here's what I did:

For solving the problem of empty `jTextField` and still running a `if` I didn't want, Use get length, put a number of letters or numbers this `jTextField` needs to have before going search in the database.

Here's the code:

```
if(jTextFieldNOME.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldCPF.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldIDADEMIN.getText().equals("") && jTextFieldIDADEMAX.getText().equals("")){

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Vazios\n");
            PreparedStatement stm=cn.prepareStatement("select * from cad_pessoa ");
            ResultSet rs = stm.executeQuery();
            
            DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel) jTableDADOS.getModel();
            tm.setRowCount(0);
        
        while(rs.next()){
            
            Object o []= {rs.getString("cad_cpf"), rs.getString("cad_nome"), rs.getString("cad_apelido"), rs.getString("cad_idade"), rs.getDate("cad_data")};
            tm.addRow(o);
                
        }
            
        }

        else if(jTextFieldNOME.getText().length()>2) {
        
        PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select cad_nome,cad_apelido,cad_cpf,cad_idade,cad_data from cad_pessoa where cad_nome like ? order by cad_nome asc, cad_cpf asc nulls last ");
        ps.setString(1,"%" + jTextFieldNOME.getText() + "%");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ps.execute();
            
        
        DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel) jTableDADOS.getModel();
        tm.setRowCount(0);

        while(rs.next()){
            
            Object o []= {rs.getString("cad_cpf"), rs.getString("cad_nome"), rs.getString("cad_apelido"), rs.getString("cad_idade"), rs.getDate("cad_data")};
            tm.addRow(o);
            
            
        }
        }
        
        else if (jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText().length()>2){
            
            PreparedStatement ps=cn.prepareStatement("select cad_nome,cad_apelido,cad_cpf,cad_idade,cad_data from cad_pessoa where cad_apelido like ? order by cad_nome asc, cad_cpf asc nulls last ");
        ps.setString(1,"%" + jTextFieldAPELIDO.getText() + "%");

            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            ps.execute();
            
        
        DefaultTableModel tm=(DefaultTableModel) jTableDADOS.getModel();
        tm.setRowCount(0);

        while(rs.next()){
            
            Object o []= {rs.getString("cad_cpf"), rs.getString("cad_nome"), rs.getString("cad_apelido"), rs.getString("cad_idade"), rs.getDate("cad_data")};
            tm.addRow(o);

        }
        
        }
```

In my case, only 2 bytes is enough to do a search and show in my `jTable`